# Successive training in neuralnet

Tags: r, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a huge trainData and I want to withdraw random subsets out of it (let's say 1000 times) and use them to train the nural network object successively. Is it possible to do by using neuralnet R package. What I am thinking about is something like:

```
library(neuralnet)

for (i=1:1000){
classA <- 2000 
classB <- 2000 
dataB <- trainData[sample(which(trainData$class == "B"), classB, replace=TRUE),] #withdraw 2000 samples from class B
dataU <- trainData[sample(which(trainData$class == "A"), classA, replace=TRUE),] #withdraw 2000 samples from class A
subset <- rbind(dataB, dataU) #bind them to make a subset
```

and then feed this subset of actual trainData to train the neuralnet object again and again like:

```
nn <- neuralnet(formula, data=subset, hidden=c(3,5), linear.output = F, stepmax = 2147483647) #use that subset for training the neural network
}
```

My question is will this neualnet object named `nn` will be trained in every iteration of loop and when loop will finish will I get a fully trained neural network object? Secondly, what will be the effect of non-convergence in the cases when the neuralnet would be unable to converge for a particular subset? Will it affect the predictions result?

Comment: My vote to close was based on this being a two part question about predicting poorly enumerated features the behavior of non-deterministic algorithm. Seems to be more appropriate on one of the other stackexchange forums, possibly the beta Machine Learning one or the established Statistics forum. (The second one would seem to be answer by just using `try` or one of its other cousins.)

Comment: @42- All I could understand from your comment is "this question is not suitable on stackoverflow. Secondly, I should try the way I have mentioned to train the neural networks" Am I right?

Comment: No. Failure to acknowledge constructive suggestion on part1. Incorrect on part 2.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest answer - No

More nuanced answer - Sort of ...

Why? - Because the `neuralnet::neuralnet` function is not designed to return the `weights` if the `threshold` is not reached within `stepmax`.  However, if the `threshold` is reached, the resulting object will contain the final `weights`.  These `weights` could then be fed to the `neuralnet` function as the `startweights` argument allowing for successive learning.  Your call would look like the following:

```
# nn.prior = previously run neuralnet object

nn <- neuralnet(formula, data=subset, hidden=c(3,5), linear.output = F, stepmax = 2147483647, startweights = nn.prior$weights)
```

However, I initially answer 'No' because choosing a `threshold` to get a suitable amount of information out of a subset while also making sure it 'converges' before `stepmax` would likely be a guessing game and not very objective.

You have essentially four options I can think of:

1. Find another package that allows for this explicitly
2. Get the `neuralnet` source code and modify it to return the `weights` even when 'convergence' isn't achieved (i.e. reaching `threshold`).
3. Take a suitably sized random subset and just build your model on that and test its' performance.  (This is actually quite common practice AFAIK).
4. Take all your subsets, build a model on each and look into combining them as an 'ensemble' model.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use k-fold validation to train many nets using library(e1071) and tune function.